# Select by default 2 or more items in ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox in wpf, with property `selectionMode="multiple"` and I want to select by default 2 or more items.

I have tried to select them with a foreach loop and:

```
listview_name.selectItem(String value);
```

But it only selects the last element.

Any idea about how this can be achieved with a listview or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your actual source code it is a bit difficult to answer. If using code-behind like it seems in your question you can simply add different elements using the `SelectedItems` collections, for example:

```
listview_name.SelectedItems.Add("string 1");
listview_name.SelectedItems.Add("string 2");
```

if you are using MVVM you can bind `SelectedItems` to an `ObservableCollection` in your `ViewModel` class, for example:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
```

add the following properties in your ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> Items{ get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<String> SelectedItems { get; } 
        = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Comment: jaja si, ahora mismo lo hago y muchas gracias otra vez